# pythonによる自作ブラウザ作成

Tags: python, python3, webview, qt5, qt-creator

【実現したいこと】
　　python3.6とQt Creatorを用いて独自のブラウザを開発したい。
　　→pythonのアプリケーションから検索したい文字列を入力し、検索ボタンをクリックすると
　　　pythonアプリ上にgoogleの検索結果がそのまま表示されるイメージ
　　
　　開発環境の詳細は最後に記載しています。

【問題点】
　　インターネットで調べると、Qt Creatorブラウザの作成方法はヒットするのだが、その通り
　　に作ることができない
　　バージョンは違うが、「https://blog.qt.io/jp/2010/04/13/simplebrowser-with-qtcreator-3/」を
　　参考に作成しようとしたところ私のQt Creatorには「qt QWebView」という名前のWidgetが存
　　在しないことに気付いた。
　　また、私の開発環境のバージョンでは「Qt WebView」に代わって「Qt WebEngine」という
　　ものが導入されているようなのだが、それでもWebView（またはそれに代わるブラウザ表示
　　用のWidget）が見つからない

[image: Widget一覧]

【教えて頂きたいこと】
　pythonとQt Creatorを用いたブラウザの作成方法を教えていただきたい
　画面作成の際に使用するはずのwidget「WebView」の表示のさせ方を教えていただきたい

【開発環境】
　Linux（Centos7)
　Python3.6
  Qt Creator 4.4.1(Based on Qt 5.9.2)
　PyQt5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問文にある https://blog.qt.io/jp/2010/04/13/simplebrowser-with-qtcreator-3/ の情報は古く、Qt5.9.2ではQtWebKitは廃止されています。
Qtでは、QtWebEngineに移行するようアナウンスしています。
移行方法は[Porting from Qt WebKit to Qt WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html)が参考になります。
([PyQt5の情報](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtWebEngine.html)を見る限り、QtWebEngineはサポートしているようなので、参考にできると思います)

なお、QtWebEngineパッケージはオプションとなっているので、インストール時に明示的に選択する必要があります。(`MaintenanceTool`なら後で追加インストールもできます)

また、QtWebViewはAndroidやiOS(やWinRT)向けですので、CentOS環境では使用できないと思います。

---

(手元の)QtCreateor4.2.1を見る限り、QtWebEngine Widgetは表示されないようですので、4.4.1でも同様の可能性があります。その場合、pythonソースに配置するよう記載することで表示できるようになると思います。(その他のボタン、テキスト入力欄はQtCreatorのデザイナで編集可能)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。WebKitは廃止されていたのですね。頂いた回答を元に考えたのですが、「WebKit廃止に伴いブラウザ表示用のウィジェットをGUI操作によって配置することはできなくなった」、「WebKit廃止によりpythonアプリでブラウザ表示のアプリを作成する場合の画面レイアウトは開発者がプログラムに直接書き込まなければならない、その時に使用するパッケージがQtWebEngine」という認識で合ってますでしょうか。

Comment: ご認識のとおりです。(そのような意図の回答でした)

Comment: 承知致しました。ありがとうございます。